# CodeIgniter 3 sessions not working for all of my users

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, cookies

I use CI sessions to allow users to signin into my site and to use store some data during the session. Here is the config of my sessions (is the config which comes out-of-the-box):

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'files';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 0;
$config['sess_save_path'] = NULL;
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;
```

The problem that I have is that when I test the sessions in my browser (Chromium v66.0.3359.117) and other devices, this works fine, but some users tell me that they cannot sign in. I think that this could be that those users don't have cookies enabled in their browsers, but I cannot check this.

Does anybody knows if there could be any problem with sessions of this is just a problem because cookies are disabled?

Comment: add debug in your code to catch cookie values browsers send to you, and see for yourself why users cant login

Comment: How can I debug the HTTP request to see the cookies? When receiving a request, I get access to the data posted (with $this->input->post()) but not to the whole HTTP request... :/

Comment: have you checked `input` class documentation for info on cookies?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: You need to be able to replicate this with a browser in front of you - anything else is guessing. You could add a hidden Easter egg in your app to help a user dump their cookies very easily, so they can copy them into an email for you (of course you should delete those cookies promptly on your side for security). In particular you need to find out if you can match a cookie they are getting with one you recognise as a valid session.

Answer (score 1):

When you use

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'files';
```

Then you cannot use

```
$config['sess_save_path'] = NULL;
```

The value of `$config['sess_save_path']` MUST be set with the absolute path to the folder that will be used for the session files. Refer to the [Files Driver](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html#files-driver) section of the documentation on Session Library for more detail.

Comment: First of all, thank you so much for your answer! I have detect this problem in production, so I really need to solve it.

What I don't understand is why, even with this configuration, I can use the sessions normally in many different machines and browsers (which makes me think that the sessions in the server works), but only in some machines doesn't work.

Please, excuse me because of my ignorance, but I need to solve this as soon as possible.

Comment: So you have assigned a value to `$config['sess_save_path'] ` and still have the problem?

Comment: And if the user won't allow cookies then sessions will not work.

Comment: I cannot confirm you if this works or not because sadly I need my users to try, so I have to wait... I don't have this issue when testing on my devices.

Comment: But... Is OK if I think that if this works fine on all the machines and browsers that I used to test, the problem is on the client-side? Because I think that if this works for me, the server is currently storing the sessions, but in some cases, not receiving the session cookie, isn't?